# Why are variables not allowed in this terraform map object

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm learning Terraform and am trying to setup some EC2 instances.

Why can I not use variables in this map object and how can I solve it?

I've read that Terraform does not support variables inside variables, but the way around this is to use local variables. But the below still doesn't allow it when I run `terraform validate`.

```
variable "ec2_details" {
    type = map(
        object(
            {
                ami_id            = string
                instance_type     = string
                #subnet_id         = string
                ec2_ebs_volumes = map(
                    object(
                        {
                            size = number
                        }
                    )
                )
            }
        )
    )
    default = {
        ec2_details = {
            ec2_1 = {
               ami_id            = local.amis
               instance_type     = local.type
               ec2_ebs_volume_size = {
                       home = {
                           size = 10
                       }
                       log = {
                           size = 20
                       }
               }
            }
            ec2_2 = {
               ami_id            = local.amis
               instance_type     = local.type
               ec2_ebs_volume_size = {
                       home = {
                           size = 10
                       }
                       log = {
                           size = 20
                       }
               }
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Error Message:

```
╷
│ Error: Invalid default value for variable
│
│   on variables.tf line 58, in variable "ec2_details":
│   58:     default = {
│   59:         ec2_details = {
│   60:             ec2_1 = {
│   61:                ami_id            = local.amis
│   62:                instance_type     = local.type
│   63:                ec2_ebs_volume_size = {
│   64:                        home = {
│   65:                            size = 10
│   66:                        }
│   67:                        log = {
│   68:                            size = 20
│   69:                        }
│   70:                }
│   71:             }
│   72:             ec2_2 = {
│   73:                ami_id            = local.amis
│   74:                instance_type     = local.type
│   75:                ec2_ebs_volume_size = {
│   76:                        home = {
│   77:                            size = 10
│   78:                        }
│   79:                        log = {
│   80:                            size = 20
│   81:                        }
│   82:                }
│   83:             }
│   84:        }
│   85:     }
│
│ This default value is not compatible with the variable's type constraint: element "ec2_details": attributes "ami_id", "ec2_ebs_volumes", and "instance_type" are required.
╵

╷
│ Error: Variables not allowed
│
│   on variables.tf line 61, in variable "ec2_details":
│   61:                ami_id            = local.amis
│
│ Variables may not be used here.
╵
╷
│ Error: Variables not allowed
│
│   on variables.tf line 62, in variable "ec2_details":
│   62:                instance_type     = local.type
│
│ Variables may not be used here.
╵
╷
│ Error: Variables not allowed
│
│   on variables.tf line 73, in variable "ec2_details":
│   73:                ami_id            = local.amis
│
│ Variables may not be used here.
╵
╷
│ Error: Variables not allowed
│
│   on variables.tf line 74, in variable "ec2_details":
│   74:                instance_type     = local.type
│
│ Variables may not be used here.
```

My files:

main.tf

```
provider "aws" {
    access_key  = var.aws_access_key_id
    secret_key  = var.aws_secret_access_key
    region      = var.aws_region
}

resource "aws_instance" "aws_vm" {
    ami             = var.ami
    instance_type   = var.instance_type
    count           = var.number_of_instances
    key_name        = var.ami_key

    tags = {
        # ec2_name  = "${format("${var.name_tag}.%03d",count.index+1)}"
        ec2_dev_name    = "${var.name_tag}$.${env}.{count.index}"
    }
```

variables.tf

```
variable "type" {
    type        = string
    description = "Instance Type"
    default     = "t2.micro"
}

variable "name_tag" {
    type        = string
    description = "Name"
    default     = "VM"
}

variable "env" {
    type        = string
    description = "Environment of EC2"
    default     = "dev"
}

variable "number_of_instances" {
    type        = number
    description = "Instances"
    default     = 1
}

variable "ami" {
    type        = string
    description = "AMI ID"
    default     = "ami-0a3c3a20c09d6f377"
}

variable "ami_key" {
    type        = string
    description = "Key Pair"
    default     = "key"
}

variable "aws_access_key_id" {}

variable "aws_secret_access_key" {}

variable "ec2_details" {
    type = map(
        object(
            {
                ami_id            = string
                instance_type     = string
                #subnet_id         = string
                ec2_ebs_volumes = map(
                    object(
                        {
                            size = number
                        }
                    )
                )
            }
        )
    )
    default = {
        ec2_details = {
            ec2_1 = {
               ami_id            = local.amis
               instance_type     = local.type
               ec2_ebs_volume_size = {
                       home = {
                           size = 10
                       }
                       log = {
                           size = 20
                       }
               }
            }
            ec2_2 = {
               ami_id            = local.amis
               instance_type     = local.type
               ec2_ebs_volume_size = {
                       home = {
                           size = 10
                       }
                       log = {
                           size = 20
                       }
               }
            }
       }
    }
}
```

locals.tf

```
locals {
  amis = "${var.ami}"
  insance_type = "${var.type}"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use variables in variables, in a map in your case, because TF does not have such functionality. All variables must be explicitly defined, and can't depend on other variables.

However, you can create so-called, [local values](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/locals) which will allow you to do what you want. So you must convert your `ec2_details` to a local value. Otherwise, you can't use variables in a definition of `ec2_details`.

Comment: I moved the block to locals.tf, but now get lots of errors. Google doesn't show anything obvious as to what is wrong. Any idea?


│ Error: Invalid reference
│
│   on locals.tf line 9, in locals:
│    9:                 ami_id            = string
│
│ A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name.

Comment: A fair bit of learning for me, but i finally got it. Thanks